# String Truncated for Some Reason in C++

Tags: c++, string, input, output

So, I was just starting C++, and I have a problem. I declared a string variable and all that, but when I have input give the variable a value, then try to display it, it only shows the first word of the sentence.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using std::string;

int main()
{
        string answer;
        cout << "Give me a sentence and I will repeat it!";
        cin >> answer;
        cout << answer;
        return 0;
}
```

For example, I entered "Yay it worked!", and it outputted "Yay"

Comment: `cin` reads input until white space is met. Use `std::getline`.

Comment: `cin >> answer;` use [`std::getline(cin,answer)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead. Know your manuals!

Answer (score 3):

The delimiter for `std::cin` is whitespace, so it only took the first word of your sentence. Like @πάνταῥεῖ said, use `std::getline(cin,answer)` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was so confused!

Answer (score 1):

As the comment explains, `cin` will only read until the first bit of whitespace is met (in your case this seems to be a space). Instead, you can use `std::getline`, which will read until a specified character, or a return by default:

```
std::string answer;
std::cout << "Give me a sentence and I will repeat it!";
std::getline(std::cin, answer):
std::cout << answer;
```

To make it read until a specified character would look like:

```
char end_char = 'a';
std::getline(std::cin, answer, end_char);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was so confused!